# WordPress Edit Page Fails with "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: wordpress

I added a simple custom HTML block to a page in Wordpress, something similar to

```
<div class="block">
  <h3>General</h3>
  <p>
    Filler Block
  </p>
  <h3>Performance</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Bullets</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then saved the page, and refreshed the page. Now the page remains blank, and in see the following error in the developer console:

```
VM5776:37 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'em' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'strong' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at window.console.error (<anonymous>:39:101)
    at Object.error (blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2)
    at Mt (blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2)
    at Yt (blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2)
    at blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Qt (blocks.min.js?ver=6.2.5:2)
    at Array.SETUP_EDITOR (editor.min.js?ver=9.2.6:17)
    at Object.dispatch (editor.min.js?ver=9.2.6:17)
```

Not sure what happened or how to fix this?